# Stored procedure enabling a user to lend multiple books to a borrower

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to work this out. Essentially, I'm trying to create a procedure in Oracle SQL Developer which enables two books to be lent out to a borrower. The tables and values are correctly setup. I feel like my created procedure may be pretty close (on the right track), but I get confused about the syntax, especially with the dates and when trying to call the procedure.

There are a few other related tables in the schema, but the gist is I'm trying to insert library/borrower records into a table called loan. The values being inserted are: 2x isbn, branchid, cardno, dateout (when book/s are borrowed) and datein (null by default, until book/s are returned). These are the column names in the loan table.

This is the procedure I've been working on:

```
create or replace procedure BorrowTwoBooks(
p_isbn in varchar2,
p_isbn2 in varchar2,
p_branchid in number,
p_cardno in number
)
is
pDate Date Default SysDate;
begin
    insert into loan values(p_isbn, p_branchid, p_cardno, pDate, null);
    insert into loan values(p_isbn2, p_branchid, p_cardno, pDate, null);
end BorrowTwoBooks;
```

and this is an example of how I'd try to call the procedure once it's created:

```
begin
BorrowTwoBooks(
'9-9996751-3-1','1','489',pDate);
'1-8744165-3-2','1','489',pDate);
end;
```

where I'm hoping the syntax would be:

```
begin
BorrowTwoBooks(
'[isbn1],'[branchid],[cardno],[dateout]);
'[isbn2],'[branchid],[cardno],[dateout]);
end;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first post, thanks everyone in advance for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your procedure the syntax would be:

```
begin
BorrowTwoBooks([isbn1],[isbn2],[branchid],[cardno]);
end;
```

try to call:

```
begin
BorrowTwoBooks('9-9996751-3-1','1-8744165-3-2','1','489');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoc created procedure that takes 4 parameters. Two of them are ISBNs of books and two others are common for both books so call should look like:

```
begin
BorrowTwoBooks(
'9-9996751-3-1','1-8744165-3-2',1,489);
end;
```

Also date is not a parameter of function. You set it to sysdate when procedure called.

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer regarding the specific case, but it seems to me that you want a procedure that have date as a parameter that is sysdate by default, but can be populated with some other date if needed.

If this is the case, your procedure should look like this:

```
create or replace procedure BorrowTwoBooks(
  p_isbn in varchar2,
  p_isbn2 in varchar2,
  p_branchid in number,
  p_cardno in number,
  p_date in date default sysdate)
is
begin
  insert into loan(isbn, branchid, cardno, dateout, datein)
  values(p_isbn, p_branchid, p_cardno, p_date, null);

  insert into loan(isbn, branchid, cardno, dateout, datein)
  values(p_isbn2, p_branchid, p_cardno, p_date, null);
end BorrowTwoBooks;
```

You can call it without providing date:

```
begin
  BorrowTwoBooks('9-9996751-3-1', '1-8744165-3-2', '1', '489');
end;
```

Or you can call it with the specific date:

```
declare
  l_date date;
begin
  l_date := to_date('2016/10/05', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
  BorrowTwoBooks('9-9996751-3-1', '1-8744165-3-2', '1', '489', l_date);
end;
```

There is another way to call the procedure - by providing parameter names. This syntax may be easier for you to understand:

```
begin
  BorrowTwoBooks(p_isbn     => '9-9996751-3-1',
                 p_isbn2    => '1-8744165-3-2',
                 p_branchid => '1',
                 p_cardno   => '489');
end;
```